# Instance level Public IPs for Resource Manager VMs

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

i just want to ask that can we have more than 5 (let's say 20) public IPs (static/dynamic) assigned to resource manager based virtual machines (in 'started' state) at a particular instance of time?
Also, do public IPs incur any charge if the respective NIC is not attached to a VM?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. [You should contact billing support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/). Yes, the unused IP incurs a charge.

["It's a Reserved IP address that isn't used in a running deployment. We charge a nominal fee (see the pricing table) for unused Reserved IP addresses."](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/)

Comment: The pricing link that you sent, seems to be for 'Classical' deployment model. See its FAQ, they allow 5 instance level IPs per subscription. but for ARM i guess this limit is 60 for dynamic public IPs.